# How can i Redirect domain AND a specific url with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have multiple domain names alias on 1 website:

I want to redirect a specific URL only if someone types in that domain *AND* the file extension.

DOMAIN1(website1.com) *AND* file "/img1.jpg" (website1.com/img1.jpg) **REDIRECT TO**:
DOMAIN2(website2.com)*AND* file "/img2.jpg" "website2.com/img2.jpg"

I only want to redirect if someone types in this exact URL

http://website1.com/img1.jpg (domain AND the img1.jpg (not any other image)
to http://website2.com/img2.jpg

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this for apache/apache2?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rule on top of your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website1\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^img1\.jpg$ http://website2.com/img2.jpg [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```